# Kentico permanent link vs direct path

Tags: kentico

I'm working on some site that all links (dynamic + hard-coded) to media library are permanent links (with getmedia...), which made it so hard to locate the exact folder of the files and update them. I've asked some developer and heard that permanent links are more secure as the system can check who have access to download the materials. Is it a fair statement and why/why not? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a fair or correct statement.  Access is set at the individual medial library directory, not an individual file level.

For example, if you have an `Images` media library which has no security behind it, you can access it directly with a URL of:

`/site/media/images/logo.png` or `/getmedia/<guid>/logo.png`

and the image will display without issue.

Now you have another media library called "Secure_Files", if you attempt to access:

`/site/media/secure_files/file1.pdf`

You'll get an error or a login page because the security is set on the

`/site/media/secure_files` directory.

Comment: Thank you Brenden. I think so, too. I've always set security at the media library folder, so when I heard the comment, I want to make sure I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k12/configuring-kentico/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-media-libraries/securing-media-libraries) on securing media libraries.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Kentico does not check the **See library content** permission for visitors on the live site. If you wish to require users to have this permission to view media library content, you need to enable the following settings in the **Content -> Media** category of the **Settings** application:

- Use permanent URLs
- Check file permissions

See the note at the very bottom of this [documentation page](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-website-content/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-media-libraries/media-libraries-security/assigning-permissions-to-media-libraries).

Answer (score 0):

**Permanent Link** is made up of:

- /getmedia/
- Guid ID
- Image Path
- .aspx

Eg: `/getmedia/C73B5-6A0-4F6-878-3C29D792014/IMG_3860.jpg.aspx`

---

**Direct Path** is made up of:

- /
- Site Name
- Media Library Folder Name
- Image Path

Eg: `/google/media/Blog-images-from-Kentico-Cloud/IMG_360.jpg`